# SSL does not work

Tags: apache-http-server, ssl, https

I am trying to add https to our url. Below is my config in httpd.conf. But when I type in the url with https, the server hangs are returns time out. The url works with http as before. HTTPS part is what I am trying to add new. I don't see any error in my logs either. Please help me in troubleshooting this please!!

```
Listen 8085
Listen 8443

SSLSessionCache shmcb:/sbclocal/data/snap/logfiles/apache/ssl_cache
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300

<VirtualHost _default_:8443>
ServerName example.com
SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol -all +SSLv3 +TLSv1
SSLCertificateFile ssl/eqiqa.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile ssl/server.key
SSLCertificateChainFile ssl/ca.crt
CustomLog /sbclocal/data/snap/logfiles/apache/ssl_request.log "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x  \"%r\" %b"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:8085>
ServerName example.com
SSLEngine off
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Have you tried a public service like this https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/? There are millions on the web, just google them.

Answer (score 1):

Seems not an issue with the posted configuration to me, the fact you're getting a timeout seems more a permission/module issue.

Please check the following:

- Whether the port `8443` is open in your firewall.
- Whether you have the apache2 SSL module enabled. To do so, run the following command:

  ```
  a2enmod ssl
  ```

  Once done, you'll probably be asked to restart your `apache2` daemon:

  ```
  /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
  ```

Comment: Thx for answering I have added the below to https.conf       LoadModule ssl_module         /sbcimp/run/pd/apache/2.2.11/modules/mod_ssl.so, but a2enmod ssl  says command not found

Comment: What I posted is a command that should be run on a terminal as `root`, not an apache2 directive.

Comment: running as root and not as apache2 command, but still I get "command not found" anyway I can see from my logs that mod_ssl/2.2.11  OpenSSL/0.9.8i WAAS/3.6.0 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.8.8 configured -- resuming normal operations" so I guess mod_ssl should be fine

Comment: Have you checked your firewall so ports `8443` and `8085` are opened?

Comment: Yes I can do a telnet and connect to it  -- telnet localhost 8443